# Ubuntu to Ubuntu remote connection

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, remote, rdp, remmina

I'm struggling to understand how to connect to another Ubuntu PC via Remmina.
I've enabled in both machines the sharing settings, but it's not clear to me what to do after.

What I tried so far is setting up a VNC connection using the IP that I find on Network settings ("192.161.1.113"), but it gives me error "Unable to connect to the VNC Server".

I tried also with RDP using the public IP but same results.

It's not a must for me to use Remmina. I'm open to all the solutions to remotely connect to another PC.

Comment: It depends on are these PCs in one network. If not, then it depends on ISP and your router config.

Comment: Yes they are on the same network. But I'd like to find a way to connect even when they are on different networks.

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1454077/edit) and add the following: The versions of Ubuntu in the two computers. Have you installed `xrdp` or are you using the Gnome Remote Desktop (via Ubuntu Setting)? If you are using the built-in gnome Remote Desktop (either RDP or Legacy VNC) then are you physically logged into that computer when you try to connect to from the other computer? Do you have automatic login turned on or do you enter the password when you login?